# What does "rect1 += rect2" mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, geometry, operators

Is this the same as UnionRects(rect1, rect2)? I'm trying to translate some Swift code to Objective C. I can't find this in the references or Googling.

After looking at this again, I think I see my problem. It's an array of rects, not a rect. Apparently, the "+=" is for the array.

This is straight out of [Apple's sample code for Photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/Shared_AssetGridViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Shared_AssetGridViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_6):

```
fileprivate func differencesBetweenRects(_ old: CGRect, _ new: CGRect) -> (added: [CGRect], removed: [CGRect]) {
        if old.intersects(new) {
            var added = [CGRect]()
            if new.maxY > old.maxY {
                added += [CGRect(x: new.origin.x, y: old.maxY, width: new.width, height: new.maxY - old.maxY)]
            }
...
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about `CGRect`? There is no built-in `+=` operator for `CGRect`. Do you have a custom implementation of such an operator?

Comment: Now that you've posted real code, your question is way off. You are not performing a union of `CGRect`. You are adding a `CGRect` to an array of `CGRect`. The square brackets are an array.

Answer (score 3):

The edited question makes it clear that you're asking about using `+=` on two `Array`s. This appends the contents of the right array to the left array, as you'd imagine. It's described in the docs under "[Accessing and Modifying an Array"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107).

Below is my original answer, preserved for anyone who stumbles onto this question looking for `+=` between `CGRect`s.

---

If `rect1` and `rect2` are `CGRect` rectangles, then `rect1 += rect2` is invalid in standard Swift.

If you see this in working code, it means that they overloaded the `+=` compound assignment operator (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID42)) to accept `CGRect`s and perform their own custom function. The only way to know what that does is to find it in the code.

Here's what the code looks like to overload `+=` with a function that unions the `CGRect`s:

```
func += (left: inout CGRect, right: CGRect) {
    left = left.union(right)
}
```

If you search your codebase for "`inout CGRect`" and various permutations thereof, you'll probably turn up the code responsible, which will help a lot in figuring out what it does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't build without also using **infix operator**. (It didn't build for me.)

Comment: @dfd It builds and runs fine for me in an iOS playground in Xcode 8.3.2. Did it give you an error?

Comment: Two. Maybe my fault, but in a brand new project they still happen with the only code you have. (And YES, my earlier comment doesn't clear up the build errors. @Robert, have you tried this function in something new? Even if it builds, doesn't the call become *let myNewRect = +-(&myRect, right my addedRect)*? The syntax - not anything else - is quite kludgy.

Comment: @dfd Works fine in a brand new playground with no other code (except the obligatory `import UIKit`). The syntax is just `rect1 += rect2`. It's a mutating function, just like `+=` always is, so `rect1` needs to be a `var` (not a `let`) to use it. Can you be any more specific about the errors you're getting?

Comment: Xcode 8.3.1. File, new project, iOS single view. Copy/paste your code straight into the MainViewController. (Nothing else.) Two errors on build. The easy one asks to declare *"Operator "+-" as Static"*. The second one - never fixed, asks for *"+-" to have at least one argument as type ViewController*. I can see this won't happen in a playground, but hopefully you can see this will happen in an actual project. (That's as specific as I can be.)

Comment: I've hesitated on down voting your answer because most of it works. But actually naming a function **+-** along with not noting that - even if it builds - means the call isn't as simple as `let rectNew += ... ?` doesn't work IMHO. Sure - `let rectNew = +=(rect1, rect2)` **might* work somehow, but huh??? It's not just syntactically poor, not just *not* Swift, I'm having a hard time understanding *how* it should work. (I mean seriously - you say to "override" +- and don't even use that verb in your answer?) Please, show me code that works in a project, not a playground. Peace.

Comment: @dfd Did you maybe put the code inside of your MainViewController class? That won't work as `+=` is not a method of `UIViewController`. Put it outside of any class, at root level where you would put a class declaration or bare function. I did it just like that (new iOS single view) and it compiles just fine.

Comment: @dfd I just realized I used "override" in the answer when I meant "overload". Maybe that's what confused you. In any case, overloading the `+=` compound assignment operator just gives you a new `+=` that works like every other `+=` you've seen. You don't write `let newInt += ...` or `let newFloat = +=(float1, float2)`, right? Operator overloading is quite Swifty, and the built-in classes do it all the time. Documentation link added to  answer.

Comment: @dfd The code in this answer works perfectly for me in a playground with Xcode 8.3.2. Using this `+=` operator, I had no problem creating to `CGRect` variables and then doing `rect2 += rect1` and getting the expected result.

Comment: I'm probably misreading this all the way around. This is straight out of Apple's sample code for Photos:

    fileprivate func differencesBetweenRects(_ old: CGRect, _ new: CGRect) -> (added: [CGRect], removed: [CGRect]) {
        if old.intersects(new) {
            var added = [CGRect]()
            if new.maxY > old.maxY {
                added += [CGRect(x: new.origin.x, y: old.maxY,
                                    width: new.width, height: new.maxY - old.maxY)]
            }

Comment: @user3311241 Update your question with these details so people actually see a clarified question.

Comment: @Robert Based on the code now posted in the updated question, this answer doesn't apply at all.

Comment: @rmaddy It specifically addresses the revised code (first paragraph, added two hours ago). I preserved my original answer because I think it could be of use to someone who finds the question based on the title. Since the actual question is based on a misreading, it should probably be closed anyway. Feel free to vote your opinion.

Comment: @Robert Oops. Sorry, somehow I glossed right over your latest update. Never mind. :)

Comment: @rmaddy This whole question is a train wreck, no worries.